# DOM XML: getElementsByTagName(...)[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xmldom

I am generating an XML file with JavaScript, when I iterate over an array of objects to enter the data in the XML it gives me the error that you see in the title. I am generating ROW nodes in which I want to put certain elements. My problem starts when I try to access X position of an element or when I try to add it to the node.

```
this.array.forEach((element) => {
    var node = xmlDoc.createElement("ROW");
    var row = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ROW");

    var fecha = xmlDoc.createElement("DATE");
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DATE")[0].textContent = element.fecha;
    row[0].appendChild(fecha);

    var descripcion1 = xmlDoc.createElement("DESCRIPTION");
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRIPTION")[0].textContent =
      element.descripcion1;
    row[0].appendChild(descripcion1);

    var descripcion2 = xmlDoc.createElement("DESCRIPTION2");
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DESCRIPTION2")[0].textContent =
      element.descripcion2;
    row[0].appendChild(descripcion2);

    var nombre = xmlDoc.createElement("NAME");
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].textContent = element.nombre;
    row[0].appendChild(nombre);

    rowset[0].appendChild(node);
  });
```

Here I leave you how I have generated the XML.

```
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "filename");

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "filename.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
  };

  var xmlString = "<ROWSET></ROWSET>";
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

  var rowset = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ROWSET");
```

Comment: At first, pull `xhttp.open` and `xhttp.send` lines out from the event handler, the request is never sent. Secondly, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: @Teemu sorry but that doesn't help me with my problem

Comment: Notice also, that `rowset` in the last snippet contains a single element. I suppose you've misstructured the example, it doesn't represent your real code.

Comment: I want a parent element called ROWSET in which to put child elements ROW with their own child elements. I don't want to repeat the ROWSET. @Teemu

Answer (score 0):

You try to get the new node from the document before appending it.

But you don't need to fetch the created node from the document, you already have it in a variable. Additionally `ParentNode.appendChild()` returns the appended node so the calls can be nested/chained.

Here is a demo:

```js
// create a document with a "ROWSET" document element node
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument('', 'ROWSET');
// get the "ROWSET" element node
var rowSet = xmlDoc.documentElement;

// create + append a "ROW", keep it in a variable 
var row = rowSet
  .appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement('ROW'));
// create + append a "DATE", set text content 
row
  .appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement('DATE'))
  .textContent = 'A Date'
// create + append a "DESCRIPTION", create + append text node
row
  .appendChild(xmlDoc.createElement('DESCRIPTION'))
  .appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode('some content'));

console.dir((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc));
```